# is fog matter, I knowthat stuff like fire arent but is fog matter?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I haven't found any other website which explains to me that fog is matter; I just need this to figure out what things are matter and which are not. For example, fire is NOT matter.

Comment: A flame is indeed made of matter, sometimes it is hot enough to be a plasma which is also matter. But a flame is a mixture of gases that are undergoing chemical reactions to emit light and heat. Fog is water vapor which is gaseous water and is thus also matter.

Comment: @Tratticus 1) If you are going to answer the question, then make it an actual answer rather than a comment 2) You typically don't want to fully answer questions like these, as it is a homework-like question where it would be better to lead the OP to the answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog

Answer (score 2):

fog is matter: it consists of tiny droplets of liquid water (which is matter) mixed into the gaseous air (which is also matter).